# Guide for created a tooltip simple?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

Why in following code(example) tooltip box come out from page, how can it fix as automatic(dynamic) with page that not come out from page?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3UzDG/ (i mane is about `how` that mouse over on it display toltip box out page) SEE image:

[image]

```
$('li a').hover(function() {

    var title = $(this).next('.tooltip').html();
    var offset = $(this).offset();

    $tooltip = $('<div />').addClass('show_tooltip').html(title);

    var delay = setTimeout(function() {

        $('body').append($tooltip);
        var width = $tooltip.outerWidth();

        var p_top = offset.top;
        var p_left = offset.left - width; 
        $tooltip.css({top: p_top, left: p_left}).fadeIn(180);

    },280);

    $(this).data('delay', delay);
    $(this).data('tooltip', $tooltip);

},function() {

    delay = $(this).data('delay');
    $tooltip = $(this).data('tooltip');
    $tooltip.remove();
    clearInterval(delay);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect if the tooltip is going to overlap the current viewport and then adjust accordingly .... there is already a jQuery plugin available for Tooltips - it does exactly what you want - check the source to see how id checks the viewport size etc http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Comment: I see this but, Which files should I find it? (jquery.bgiframe.js Or jquery.dimensions.js OR jquery.tooltip.js Or chili-1.7.pack.js Or ?)